# Send data between two classes

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, class

I had to work with accessibility services in android
I have two classes “myaccessibilityclass” (which extends accessibility services) and “my custom class” (which extends react native module)
Now I want data in “myaccessibilityclass” into “my custom class”
How can I get this please help
I’m working in android section of react native app

I an new to oops world (new to even programming) so tried some things but those didn’t work

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you include an example of what you're trying to do

Comment: Have you tried using interface?, please test with that